# Unable to run apps like Turbo C++

Tags: c++

I am unable to download applications such as Turbo C++ and related applications even though i have DOS box terminal. When I try to open the Turbo C++ setup it doesn't open and I get a message saying

```
application x-ms download type is not supported.
```

Comment: I think you are trying to install `.exe` file in Ubuntu which is not supported unless you install a utility called `wine`.

Comment: Are you following [this guide?](http://www.turboc8.com/2013/11/turbo-c-for-ubuntulinux-using-dosbox.html)

Answer (score 1):

As @Rahul said in the comments, you are probably trying to install .exe file. You have two options to run C++ in Ubuntu.

1. If you want Turbo C++ in particular which is meant for Windows OS, then follow @Pankaj Gautham's answer.

Or

2. Install Ubuntu related C++ compiler, g++.

To install g++ type in terminal, `sudo apt-get install g++`. This will install the latest g++ package.
Then write any C++ program in gedit or in any of your favorite text editor, and save as "filename.cpp".
For compiling and running C++ program, follow [this link](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2013/03/how-to-write-and-run-cc-programs-in.html).

For your reference. Compiling:

```
g++ progcpp.cpp -o progcpp
```

Running:

```
./progcpp
```

Comment: This is way better than using turboc++ !

Answer (score 0):

> One need to follow the below steps in order  to run Turbo-C in Ubuntu [Linux] .We need DoxBox Emulator to launch Turbo-C compiler in Ubuntu.

### Steps :-

1. Install DosBox Emulator using Ubuntu Software Center
2. Download Borland Turbo C++ Compiler From [Here](http://turbo-c.soft32.com/).
3. It will be downloaded in "**Downloads**" Folder
4. Cut the Zip File & Extract the downloaded file "**tc3**" in the **Home** Directory
5. Now open DosBox
6. Type the following commands in the DosBox Window
   **mount c ~ [**Note if you getting error **"Drive C is already Mounted as/with Local directory home/username/" type the command "C:" ]

       C:

       cd tc3 [Here "tc3" is the folder name]

       install.exe**
7. Now Turbo Window will pop-up 
       Click Enter
8. Now it will ask you " **Enter the SOURCE drive to use** :"   = Enter "**C**" in the place of default drive "A".
9. Press "**Enter**" when it ask asks about SOURCE Path
10. Use UP/Down arrow keys .Select "Start Installation"
11. Now the installation goes on.once completed press any key to exit
12. After the installation you will find a new folder named as "TC" inside your Home folder
13. Now you have to mount the new folder "TC"
14. open DosBox Emulator window & Type "cd.." if the window is not closed.If the you have closed the DosBox window you have to write the following commands to mount the new folder
    **Z:\>mount c ~

        Z:\>

        C:\>cd tc

        C:\TC>cd BIN

        C:\TC\ BIN>tc.exe**
15. Now the Turbo C complier window will be shown.Write the programs and execute it as you have done on the windows
16. If you want open Turbo C compiler in Ubuntu you need to run to write the **Step: 14** commands in DosBox Emulator to launch the compiler
17. Thats' it

> You can also watch a tutorial about this installation.
>   **Youtube** - [Installing Turbo C++ in Ubuntu](https://youtu.be/B5kOGYC5hLE)